# Aeroo reports definition

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9, aeroolib

I'm trying to make reports in Odoo 9, I successfully made at installing Aeroo reports in v9 since it's not supported at the moment.I know there are ways to make reports using the web interface but it's not much easier for the end-users, so I want to make define reports like in Qweb reports, by defining a report and its template , but I couldn't find a way to do it with aeroo.Here is where I'm stuck:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>

        <!-- Report Definition, registration -->
        <report
            id="student_profile"
            string="Student profile"
            model="student.student"
            <!-- I changed report-type from qweb-pdf to aeroo  -->
            report_type="aeroo"
            <!-- Usually name refer to the implementation of the template, but for aeroo the template is just .odt file-->
            name="student.student_profile_template"
        />

    </data>
</openerp>
```

How can I refer to `.odt` file of the template from here (That's if I'm doing it the right way)?

Comment: You want to create a `.odt` file from a Qweb template using Aeroo Reports. Am I right? Do you know if that is possible in other versions of Odoo? Because if that is true then maybe we can use the same Qweb template that we used for webkit. That would be awesome

Comment: I just want to predefine aeroo report template, but I don't know how

Comment: Ah! OK, you must do it directly with LibreOffice. You can check [here](http://www.alistek.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) what directives you can use. And you can whatch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kk5pQyJwY6w) to check how you have to add the fields to the document